# fatal error when try to serve geth in ipc

Tags: go-ethereum, ipc

I have initialized my own genesis block and started

```
geth --datadir pom
```

Then I want to use `"personal"` so I started

```
geth --nodiscover --ipcpath pom/geth.ipc --networkid 31337 --rpc --rpcaddr 192.168.225.235 --rpcport 22000 --rpcapi admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3,quorum,raft --port 21000
```

and I'm receiving the error

```
Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: genesis mismatch: 0xd4e56740f876aef8c010b86a40d5f56745a118d0906a34e69aec8c0db1cb8fa3 (leveldb) !=  (ancients)
```

I don't understand this error and I'm searching the google and some link says re initialize the chain. So I have deleted and initialize the genesis many times. Can someone help to solve this error? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
$ geth --datadir pom
```

you are not initializing a custom chain, you are just starting the client on the Mainnet using a custom folder.

To inizialize a custom network you need to use the `init` parameter with a genesis file, like this:

```
$ geth --datadir pom init [yourGenesisFile.json]
```

And after that you need to pass the custom folder value - `pom` in your case - even when running the client, so your command will become:

```
$ geth --datadir pom --nodiscover --ipcpath pom/geth.ipc --networkid 31337 --rpc --rpcaddr 192.168.225.235 --rpcport 22000 --rpcapi admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3,quorum,raft --port 21000
```

Comment: I already done init. But I run as two command geth --datadir pom and in another command i try to attach ipc. But combine this to single command works